Ionic Capacitor Electron - How to open internal link in new window?
I just started using ionic 8/Capacitor 5 electron. I am trying to figure out how to open an internal route link in an window? For example I want to navigate to an internal angular route /form/:id. In my PWA version all i do is use window.open with the base url eg window.open("https://client.myapp.com/form/111").
I have gone through the electron/capacitor docs but unfortunately not much information. Any idea how to do this in Ionic Capacitor Electron?

What you mean by Internal routing?? are you trying to open Browser? or just navigation to other routes within electron app?

Thanks for yoru reply just navigating to routes within the electron app?

the simple app router should be enough for the routing within app. same as web.

Capacitor has a plugin that handles internal link routing: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser

This will work only in the browser and not desktop version
